# Does IIS give each connected user a thread?

Tags: c#, iis

I am doing some research on developing thread safe applications. I know users can use multiple threads on the same application (if the CPU works with more than one thread) but I am not sure what happens, and how IIS handles users when you have 5 users using the same application for example.

What does IIS do, are all the users working on the same thread? or are they given a thread each for example?

I am a newbie when it comes to IIS, so please bear with me. My question will help me understand whether I need to lock public static methods in my code (where thread safety is important).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525101(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a good read to start with - [ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.5, IIS 7.0, and IIS 6.0](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-75-iis-70-and-iis-60_1_11_30564612.html). The important thing you should remember - IIS will not create threads for users, it will create threads for concurrent calls. And of course you should create thread safe static methods, if they are not the pure.

Comment: Don't forget session state can cause concurrent calls from the same user to serialize.

Comment: does that mean that persistent connection frameworks, like [SignalR](http://signalr.net) will block one thread per connected users ?

Comment: @SteveB, It totally depends on the implementation. A good implementation would use async calls and not block threads. You can achieve persistent connections without blocking one thread per user.

Comment: @SteveB I'm not familiar with the `SignalR`, but it is very wasteful to use one thread per user.

Comment: @nunespascal: do you have some link, I'm a bit confused with the concept of async call at the infrastructure level (how does asp/net + IIS handle such calls) ?

Comment: @SteveB: Take a look here at how asp.net manages threads during an async request http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx