# Using static functions in a asp.net 3.5 website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a ASP.NET webapplication in which I use several classes containing static functions for retreiving database values and such (based on session of user so their results are session specific, not application wide).

These functions can also be called from markup, which makes developing my GUI fast and easy.

Now I am wondering: is this the right way of doing things, or is it better to create a class, containing these functions and create an instance of the class when needed?

What will happen when there are a lot of visitors to this website? Will a visitor have to wait until the function is 'ready' if it's also called by another session? Or will IIS spread the workload over multiple threads?

Or is this just up to personal preferences and one should test what works best?

EDIT AND ADDITIONAL QUESTION:

I'm using code like this:

```
public class HandyAdminStuff
{
  public static string GetClientName(Guid clientId)
  {
    Client client = new ClientController().GetClientById(clientId);
    return client.Name;
  }
}
```

Will the Client and ClientController classes be disposed of after completion of this function? Will the GarbageCollector dispose of them? Or will they continue to 'live' and bulk up memory everytime the function is called?

---

** Please, I don't need answers like: 'measure instead of asking', I know that. I'd like to get feedback from people who can give a good answer an maybe some pro's or cons, based on their experience. Thank you.

Comment: Do your functions also modify/insert some DB data or they are just fetching data?

Comment: They do both fetching and upserts, but the upserts are mostly done in a backend, while the website almost only does fetching.

Answer (score 1):

"Will a visitor have to wait until the function is 'ready' if it's also called by another session?"

Yes. It may happen if you have thread safe function body, or you perform some DB operations  within transaction that locks DB.

Take a look at these threads:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1933971.aspx?THEORY%20High%20load%20on%20static%20methods%20How%20does%20net%20handle%20this%20situation%20

[Does IIS give each connected user a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096954/does-iis-give-each-connected-user-a-thread)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have instance based objects because they can also be easily disposed (connections possibly?) and you wouldn't have to worry about multithreading issues, additional to all the problems "peek" mentioned.

For example, each and every function of your static DAL layer should be atomic. That is, no variables should be shared between calls inside the dal. It is a common mistake in asp.net to think that **[TreadStatic]** data is safe to be used inside static functions. The only safe pool for storing per request data is the **Context.Items** pool, everything else is unsafe.

Edit:
I forgot to answer you question regarding IIS threads. Each and every request from your customers will be handled by a different thread. As long as you are not using Session State, concurrent requests from the same user will be also handled concurrently by different threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use static function for retrieving data. This because these static functions will make your code harder to test, harder to maintain, and can't take advantage of any oo principals for design. You will end up with more duplicate code, etc.

Comment: Would you please explain why you think code will be harder to test? FYI: all my businessmodels are used in an OOP way extensively. The static functions just retreive and sometimes change data. I use them primarily to get data and show this in the markup of webpages.

Comment: Writing unittests on instances is easier then on static functions. You can't use oo techniques for stubbing.